# gsub! not doing anything in rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to import a csv file into my database and after hours of fun I've pinpointed what the problem is: the remarks field sometimes has quotes in it and if I replace `\"` with `\""` then the field gets imported no problem.

I've written a rake task to import the csv file and use gsub to replace `\"` with `\""` but gsub isn't doing anything. Here's the rake task with the complete code:

**csvproperty.rake**

```
require 'csv'

task :csv_to_properties => [:environment] do
CSV.foreach("lib/assets/wp_realty_listingsdb.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
row[remarks=23].gsub!(/\"/, '\""')

Property.create!(row.to_hash)
end
end
```

The remarks field is the 23rd column (starting counting from 0), but I've tried it with 22 and 24 with no luck. I know this code works because I used the exact same rake task on another app using gsub to remove a comma from a price field and it worked fine, why isn't it replacing `\"` with `\""`?

EDIT:

For example, the remarks for this property on line 8 of the csv file are:

```
"THIS HOME EPITOMIZES THE  VERY  ESSENCE OF A PERFECT \"10\"."
```

The csv tried to escape the quotes by doing `\"` but it's not enough, it needs to be `\""` because if I run this command:

```
rake csv_to_properties
```

then I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Missing or stray quote in line 8
```

But if I manually change it to `\""` then the error moves on to the next line that has quotes:

```
rake aborted!
Missing or stray quote in line 24
```

But if I don't change it manually and rely on gsub to make the change the error message remains on line 8. Why isn't gsub replacing `\"` with `\""`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're escaping the `"` or it actually is `\"`. What exactly does the text look like? `sometext"` or `sometext\"`?

Comment: see edit. The issue isn't so much about escaping quotes as I've worked out that it needs to be \"" but the issue is why isn't the gsub doing as it's told?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not saving. Try `gsub!('"', "'")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> s = "THIS HOME EPITOMIZES THE  VERY  ESSENCE OF A PERFECT \"10\"."
> puts s
=> THIS HOME EPITOMIZES THE  VERY  ESSENCE OF A PERFECT "10".

> s.gsub!(/(\")/, '\""')
=> "THIS HOME EPITOMIZES THE  VERY  ESSENCE OF A PERFECT \\\"\"10\\\"\"."
> puts s
=> THIS HOME EPITOMIZES THE  VERY  ESSENCE OF A PERFECT \""10\"".
```